# React - MUI5 - Overriding global theme for InputBase changes all other textfield styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to override the style of all `<InputBase />` components in my global theme.

```js
       MuiInputBase: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    "&.MuiInputBase-root.Mui-focused": {
                        borderBottom: "1px solid #2660BE",
                    },
                    "&.MuiInputBase-root.Mui-error": {
                        borderBottom: "1px solid #EB0202",
                        color: "#EB0202",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
```

But I notice that it is overriding the styles of even `<TextField />` and `<OutlinedInput />` components. Is there any way to override JUST `<InputBase />` in global theming? Or should I use styled components?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can include the `:not` pseudo class

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

to exclude all other classes that derive from `InputBase`, e.g.

`.MuiInputBase-input:not(.MuiOutlinedInput-input):not(.MuiTextField-root)`

Comment: How do I do this with `createTheme`?